# asp jpg file submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, cors

How do I configure a classical ASP source that sends jpg files stored on a server to another server? ( multipart/form-data )
The client is trying to deal with it, so we are having a problem with CORS.
The iframe can be processed on request, but when you receive the return value, you will have a problem with CORS.

Comment: what do you mean by "ASP source"?

Comment: enable CORS (Cross-Origin Requests) on the recieving server, and only do this on the specific action https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-7.0